# Laravel controller create variable database using if-else

Tags: php, laravel

I'm still new to Laravel and PHP. I'm creating a website that can create id that log in with my ID generate that can log in with different view as the different user. Then i'm trying to use if-else with `str_contains` in it. So this for creating a new user to database. But still got an error message:

> ErrorException in UserController.php line 26:
>   Undefined variable: UserID

Here some of my UserController.php

```
$usertype = $request['UserType'];
$user1 = str_contains($usertype, 'Customer');
$user2 = str_contains($usertype, 'Marketing');
$user3 = str_contains($usertype, 'Designer');

if($user1 == true){
    $UserID = 'CU';
} else if($user2 == true){
    $UserID = 'MK';
} else if($user3 == true){
    $UserID = 'DG';
}

$UserID = $UserID+rand(10000, 99999); //line 26
```

So line 26 is to called `$UserID` to be add an generate random numeric.

I found what is wrong with my code. It is not because the declaration of variable it's the `str_contains` that outputing `1` not `true`.

```
$usertype = $request['UserType'];

if(str_contains($usertype, 'Customer') == 1){
    $UserID = 'CU';
}else if(str_contains($usertype, 'Designer') == 1){
    $UserID = 'MK';
}else if(str_contains($usertype, 'Marketing') == 1){
    $UserID = 'DG';
}

$UserID .= rand(10000, 99999);
```

Comment: add `else $userID = 0`. Always declare variable before use, so declare it before `if`

Comment: Thanks. It's working with the error but now if-else condition is not work now. So my database '$UserID' is contain just randomize numeric not with condition on if-else that i add with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its because your `if` condition does not match with condition thats why `$userID` is not initialized. You have to first initialize `$userID` first

```
$UserID = ''; //initialize with empty string or what ever you want
if($user1 == true){
   $UserID = 'CU';}
else if($user2 == true){
   $UserID = 'MK';}
else if($user3 == true){
   $UserID = 'DG';}

$UserID = $UserID+rand(10000, 99999);
```

Comment: Thanks. It's working with the error but now if-else condition is not work now. So my database `$UserID` is contain just randomize numeric not with condition on if-else that i add with it. Is it the `str_contains` that wrong or is the if-else condition.

Comment: You have to check your output of  `$user1`, `$user2` and `$user3`